# Is a vector field a mathematical field?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, definition, vector-fields

I would like to ask if a vector field is  mathematical field which is defined to be  a set on which addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are defined, and behave as when they are applied to rational and real numbers.

I can see that a vector field satisfies addition, subtraction, multiplication but I am not sure about division. Is this just terminology or is a vector field a field in the mathematical sense?

Comment: No, absolutely not. It is just a matter of giving the same name to different things.

Comment: No. In other languages, e.g. in Polish, these object have different names: `ciało` (of numbers) and `pole` (of vectors).

Comment: A vector field in general does *not* have multiplication in the sense of a field.  Vector field has scalar multiplication (e.g. $F \times V \to V$), field has multiplication of elements (e.g. that would be $V \times V \to V$).

Comment: In French as well: 'corps' vs 'champ'.

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification and interesting linguistic information.

Comment: Also in German "Körper" vs. "Vektorfeld". Very unfortunate that the same term is reused in English (and some other languages) for completely different things.
Thank you for your question!

Answer (score 8):

No, these are distinct concepts. A field (in Algebra) is what you think a field is. But a vector field is, roughly speaking, an assignment of a vector to each point in a space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by field they are referring to space(manifold), think  of a paddy field.

Vector field is assigning a vector to each element of this field.

Answer (score 0):

A vector field in differential geometry is a smooth section of the tangent bundle.  A field in abstact algebra is a commutative ring in which every nonzero element is a unit.  Two entirely different notions.